# Symfony 3.4: How to access bundle configuration in YAML

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml, symfony-3.4

I'd like to ask if there is a way to access bundle configuration from YAML of that bundle.

Specifically, implementing `Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface` I define that my bundle needs some configuration. User puts that configuration in their `app/config/bundles/my_bundle.yml` with all the keys I require for my bundle.

`my_bundle:
    magic_key: '42'`

Now in my bundle I have `Resources/config/services.yml` in which I configure some services and I need `magic_key` for one of them.

Since I know `magic_key` is set (because of `ConfigurationInterface`) I now am able access that key in a class extending `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension`, get definition of particular service and set argument for that.

However I'd like to do this in `Resources/config/services.yml` located in my bundle instead of using and `Extension` class.
I've read at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/expression_language.html that it should be possible using `parameter` or `container` functions, but I'm not able to do that.

The reasoning behind that is that I want to have configure my bundle services at single location - the YAML file - as opposed to current situation where it is split between YAML and `Extension.php`.

Is it indeed possible? What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your configuration in parameters in your MyBundleExtension class like this:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->setParameter('my_bundle', $config);
}
```

Then you can add "%my_bundle%" in service arguments.

Comment: Thank you, but that just passes the whole array of configuration to the service.